# Validating JSON before deserializing into C# object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

If a JavaScript object in JSON is not going to deserialize into the C# object I want, how can I interrogate it to provide an error message explaining what is wrong with the input? (Assuming the JSON format is correct, just the data is not valid.)

**My C# class:** (simplified)

```
public class Dependent
{
    public Dependent()
    {
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**Test code to deserialize:**

```
string dependents = @"[
                            {
                                ""FirstName"": ""Kenneth"",
                                ""DateOfBirth"": ""02-08-2013""
                            },
                            {
                                ""FirstName"": ""Ronald"",
                                ""DateOfBirth"": ""08-07-2011""
                            }
                      ]";

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

List<Dependent> deps = new List<Dependent>();
deps = jss.Deserialize<List<Dependent>>(dependents);
```

This all works. EXCEPT if a non-date is passed in as the birthday, it will fail to deserialize.

I want to provide an error message like "Dependent 2 date of birth is not a valid date." or "Dependent 2 must be under age 18."

**How can I validate the details of the JSON if it won't deserialize into my object?**

**Possible solution:**

```
public class SerializableDependent
{
    public SerializableDependent()
    {
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And then I should not get any errors having everything as a string, and I can loop through the objects and do my validation. This seems wrong though.

Comment: Doesn't the exception explain the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer` does not support extensive error handling. I suggest you use the [Json.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/json). You can use the `JsonSerializerSettings` object's `Error` event handler to capture more details on what went wrong. Information on using this member is present in the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm).

For your above code snippet, a handler which populates an array of error messages can be written as follows:

```
public class Dependent
{
    public Dependent()
    {
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } // Use a nullable object to hold the error value
}

void DeserializeTest()
{
   string dependents = @"[
                            {
                                ""FirstName"": ""Kenneth"",
                                ""DateOfBirth"": ""02-08-2013""
                            },
                            {
                                ""FirstName"": ""Ronald"",
                                ""DateOfBirth"": ""asdf""
                            }
                      ]";

    var messages = new List<string>();

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(){
        Error = (s,e)=>{
            var depObj = e.CurrentObject as Dependent;
            if(depObj != null)
            {
                messages.Add(string.Format("Obj:{0} Message:{1}",depObj.FirstName, e.ErrorContext.Error.Message));
            }
            else 
            {
                messages.Add(e.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            }
            e.ErrorContext.Handled = true; // Set the datetime to a default value if not Nullable
        }
    };
    var ndeps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dependent[]>(dependents, settings);
    //ndeps contains the serialized objects, messages contains the errors
}
```

Comment: I ended up changing DateOfBirth to string. It feels wrong, but so does making DateTime nullable when it really shouldn't be null. But I did try this out and would have worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can validate `JSON` in `C#` using [**JSON Schema**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) (framework provided by Newtonsoft). It allows to validate `JSON` data. Below is the code illustrating how it looks like. For more details you could read the article [Validating JSON with JSON Schema in C#](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/validating-json-with-json-schema-in-c.html)

```
     string myschemaJson = @"{
        'description': 'An employee', 'type': 'object',
        'properties':
        {
           'name': {'type':'string'},
           'id': {'type':'string'},
           'company': {'type':'string'},
           'role': {'type':'string'},
           'skill': {'type': 'array',
           'items': {'type':'string'}
        }
     }";

     JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(myschemaJson);

     JObject employee = JObject.Parse(@"{
        'name': 'Tapas', 'id': '12345', 'company': 'TCS',
        'role': 'developer',
        'skill': ['.NET', 'JavaScript', 'C#', 'Angular',
        'HTML']
     }");
     bool valid = employee.IsValid(schema);
     // True

     JsonSchema schema1 = JsonSchema.Parse(myschemaJson);

     JObject employee1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
        'name': null, 'id': '12345', 'company': 'TCS',
        'role': 'developer',
        'skill': ['.NET', 'JavaScript', 'C#', 'Angular',
        'HTML']
     }");

     IList<string> messages;
     bool valid1 = employee1.IsValid(schema1, out messages);
     // False
     // "Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line 2,
     // position 24."


     JsonSchema schema2 = new JsonSchema();
     schema2.Type = JsonSchemaType.Object;
     schema2.Properties = new Dictionary<string, JsonSchema>
     {
        { "name", new JsonSchema
           { Type = JsonSchemaType.String } },
        { "id", new JsonSchema
           { Type = JsonSchemaType.String } },
        { "company", new JsonSchema
           { Type = JsonSchemaType.String } },
        { "role", new JsonSchema
           { Type = JsonSchemaType.String } },
        {
           "skill", new JsonSchema
           {
              Type = JsonSchemaType.Array,
              Items = new List<JsonSchema>
                 { new JsonSchema
                    { Type = JsonSchemaType.String } }
           }
        },
     };

     JObject employee2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
        'name': 'Tapas', 'id': '12345',
        'company': 'TCS', 'role': 'developer',
        'skill': ['.NET', 'JavaScript', 'C#', 'Angular',
        'HTML']
     }");
     bool valid2 = employee2.IsValid(schema2);
     // True
```

Comment: this librery is not free over 1000 call per hour 
`: The free-quota limit of 1000 schema validations per hour has been reached. Please visit http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema to upgrade to a commercial license.
`

Comment: Voted down as it has the 1000 limit, and created a working example without limits. see below.

Answer (score 0):

NewtonSoft has the 1000 pr hour. So here is another way, without newtonSoft.

I have implemented it in a Action filter on a controller as a working example.
This does not have the 1000 limit. You can use the build in error or customize one like i did in the StringToShort

This will validate the model, before it gets to the controller, response is a nice message so the receiver can use it for what ever. (we actually use different languages in out prod version. This one uses a "hardcoded" test, but it's easy to put you preferences.

Here is the ActionFilter

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NJsonSchema;
using NJsonSchema.Validation;

namespace CoreApiFunctions.Filter
{
    public class PersonModelValidationFilter3 : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _rulebookPath;
        private HttpValidationProblemDetails problemDetails = new HttpValidationProblemDetails();
        public PersonModelValidationFilter3(string rulebookPath)
        {
            _rulebookPath = rulebookPath;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executing action {context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}");
            //Activity.Current.add.AddTag("httpContext", context);

            string schemaFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _rulebookPath);

            var rulebookJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(schemaFilePath);

            JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(rulebookJson).Result;

            foreach (var argument in context.ActionArguments)
            {
                var model = argument.Value;
                if (model != null)
                {
                    JObject incomingModel = JObject.FromObject(model);
                    var errors = schema.Validate(incomingModel);
                    foreach (var error in errors)
                    {
                        string actualValue = incomingModel.SelectToken(error.Property)?.ToString();
                        AddValidationErrorToOutput(error, actualValue);
                    }
                }
            }



            if (problemDetails.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                problemDetails.Status = 400;
                problemDetails.Title = "One or more validation errors occurred.";
                problemDetails.Type = "https://www.example.com/validation-error";
                problemDetails.Detail = "Please correct the validation errors and try again.";
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
            }

        }

        private void AddValidationErrorToOutput(ValidationError error, string actualValue)
        {

            string customMessage = error.Kind.ToString();

            if (error.Kind == ValidationErrorKind.StringTooShort)
            {
                //int actualLength = error.Value?.ToString().Length ?? 0;
                int actualLength = actualValue?.Length ?? 0;
                customMessage = $"String {error.Property} is too short, length is {actualLength}, minimum is {error.Schema.MinLength}.";
            }
            problemDetails.Errors.Add(error.Property, new string[] { customMessage });


        }



        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executed action {context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}");
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executed action {context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}");
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Executed action {context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}");
        }


    }
}
```

Here is a Json schema to validate the model. (a bit elaborate, but just to show the possibilities)

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 5 
    },
    "vatNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "vatNumber",
    "name"
  ],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "country": {
            "properties": {
              "id": { "const": "GB" }
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [ "country" ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "vatNumber": {
            "pattern": "^GB([\\d]{9}|[\\d]{12}|GD[\\d]{3}|HA[\\d]{3})$",
            "errorMessage": "Can be GB000000000(000), GBGD000 or GBHA000"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "country": {
            "properties": {
              "id": { "const": "RU" }
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [ "country" ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "vatNumber": {
            "pattern": "^[0-9]{9}$",
            "errorMessage": "Can be only 9 digits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the controller. It uses a "Person" model. Shown down below.
I find this to be the easiest way to add new filters and schemas directly in the code. Schemas can be modified outside the code. (easier deploy)

```
[HttpPost("TestValidation3")]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(PersonModelValidationFilter3), Arguments = new object[] { "conditional-fields-validaiton-schema.json" })]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ProducesErrorResponseType(typeof(HttpValidationProblemDetails))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestValidation3(Person3 person)
    {

        // Code goes here

        // Normal response.
        return Ok();
    }
```

Here is the model(s)

```
public class Person3
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string vatNumber { get; set; }
    public Country country { get; set; }
}

    
public class Country
{
    public string id { get; set; }    
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

[image]