# Validating and Correcting JSON data during or after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, validation

I have been agonizing over this problem for a few days now and have no hope left. I'm still in the early stages of learning C#, so excuse me if my explanations or understanding are lacking.

My scenario is that I have a need to access an API and download the data as JSON then deserialize it into a class. At the moment, things work as they should, however every variable is defined as String which means I need to convert and manipulate data that should be int/double on the fly constantly as the API can give "N/A" for these data. The impression I get is relying on everything being string is bad practice.

So how should I implement it? I need to be able to store the data as the correct type while keeping in mind that it could be wrong.

Example of properties with wrong type

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Year { get; set; } // Wanted int. Often has an end year "2010-2014"
public string Metascore { get; set; } // Wanted double. Could be "N/A"
```

The only way I can imagine solving this is by having two classes: the first one being the original string-only class, then having the second being an almost identical class with the desired properties that uses the data from the original then converts it.

My problem with that is that the class already has a few dozen properties, so duplicating it seems nearly as wasteful as the original problem. Regardless, I would like to know an alternative for future use anyway.

EDIT:
Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186892/validating-json-before-deserializing-into-c-sharp-object?rq=1), though unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can deserialize the json to `JObject` and than load it your self

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public RootObject(JObject obj)
        {
            Title = obj["Title"].ToString();
            var year = obj["year"].ToString();
            Year = year == "N/A" ? 0 : int.Parse(year);
            var metascore = obj["Metascore"].ToString();
            Metascore = metascore == "N/A" ? 0 : int.Parse(metascore);
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; } 
        public double Metascore { get; set; } 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Title\":\"test\",\"year\":\"2012\",\"Metascore\":\"N/A\"}";
        RootObject root = new RootObject(JObject.Parse(json));
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming that
`Metascore = metascore == "N/A" ? 0 : int.Parse(metascore);`

should be
`Metascore = metascore == "N/A" ? 0 : double.Parse(metascore);`

If so, it's been working great so far. Just need to change the code to implement it. Thanks so much for relieving me of this headache.

I'll mark this as the answer if I have no followups.

Comment: Also could you explain what  `Metascore = metascore == "N/A" ? 0 : double.Parse(metascore);` does?

Comment: it is short syntax for if metascore == "n/a" return 0 else convert to int